# How can I debounce a C# Windows Forms ComboBox.PreviewKeyDown event?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, debouncing

I want to debounce a Windows Forms ComboBox.PreviewKeyDown event because it seems to always fire duplicate events. I would prefer only 1 event per keystroke.

For example:

1. Create a new C# Windows Forms application (I tried .NET 4.6.2 and 4.7.2)
2. Add a ComboBox and a TextBox to the main Form
3. Set the textBox1.Multiline = true;
4. Add the comboBox1.PreviewKeyDown event handler code to append results to the textBox1.Text
5. Run and observe every keystroke in the comboBox1 fires the PreviewKeyDown event 2 times!

```cs
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBox_Bounce
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      // Hookup event here in code, not in the Designer
      this.comboBox1.PreviewKeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(this.comboBox1_PreviewKeyDown);
    }

    private void comboBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
      this.textBox1.Text += "comboBox1_PreviewKeyDown=" + e.KeyCode.ToString() +  + System.Environment.NewLine;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Platform: Visual Studio 16.5.4, Windows 10 [1809] all current updates.

Comment: Are you also setting `comboBox1_PreviewKeyDown` as a handler for the `PreviewKeyDown` event in the designer?

Comment: No: in the example the Only handler is in code.  I tried both designer handler and the += code ways separately with the same results.  I put the += code handler in my question for clarity. If I add a `textBox1.PreviewKeyDown`  handler, the textBox1 event will fire properly only once per keystroke.  This issue seems to be specific to the ComboBox.

Comment: My problem with the bouncing behavior is: I did not find the documented, so I do not know if it is consistent enough for me to safely simply ignore every other ComboBox.PreviewKeyDown event.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=netframework-4.8): "You should not put any logic in the PreviewKeyDown event handler, other than to set the IsInputKey property. Instead, you should put your logic in the KeyDown event handler."

Comment: The ComboBox is a composited Control... There's the MessageLoop and the Dispatcher. Why are you using this event instead of KeyDown? Or override WndProc or ProcessCmdKey of a custom control?

Comment: For *TnTinMn*: The "IsInputKey" does not change the issue of duplicate events.

Comment: For *Jimi*: my implementations uses custom controls that work around this issue.  However the duplicate events annoy me. If the behavior is "by design" it would be nice if the *sender* in the event would include additional information like: was the event from the ComboBox's Text or DropDown List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Control.PreviewKeyDown` should only be used for testing for a particular key press and then to set the `Control.IsInputKey` to true if that is the case, otherwise you should use the `Control.KeyDown` event handler.

See [Control.PreviewKeyDown Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Implementing [ChrisBD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61252843/3519108) above works for the example:

```cs
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ComboBox_Bounce
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.comboBox1.PreviewKeyDown += this.comboBox1_PreviewKeyDown;
      this.comboBox1.KeyDown += ComboBox1_KeyDown;
    }

    private void ComboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
      this.textBox1.Text += "comboBox1_KeyDown=" + e.KeyCode.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine;
    }

    private void comboBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
      this.textBox1.Text += "comboBox1_PreviewKeyDown=" + e.KeyCode.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine;
      e.IsInputKey = true;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]